# How to use SSML in Alexa Skill + Lambda + Js

Tags: java, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to use SSML in my Alexa Skill. I use Lambda as my service endpoint and Js to program it. Now my question is, how do I correctly implement this in my skill? I'm using the following function to use SSML:

```
function buildSSMLSpeechletResponse(title, output, repromptText, shouldEndSession) {
    return {
        outputSpeech: {
            type: "SSML",
            ssml: output
        },
        card: {
            type: "Simple",
            title: "SessionSpeechlet - " + title,
            content: "SessionSpeechlet - " + output
        },
        reprompt: {
            outputSpeech: {
                type: "SSML",
                text: repromptText
            }
        },
        shouldEndSession: shouldEndSession
    };
}
```

My code:

```
function onLaunch(launchRequest, session, callback) {
    console.log("onLaunch requestId=" + launchRequest.requestId
        + ", sessionId=" + session.sessionId);

    var cardTitle = "Hello, World!";
    var speechOutput = { type: "SSML",
    ssml: "<speak>Welcome to Hubo help. <amazon:effect name='whispered'>You can ask questions like</amazon:effect>: 'How do I paint a wall?'. Now what can I help you with?.</speak>", };
    callback(session.attributes,
        buildSSMLSpeechletResponse(cardTitle, speechOutput, "", true));
}
```

I think I made a mistake at the callback? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the [Alexa Skills Kit SDK for Node.js](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs) you can just include the SSML markup in the text to emit.

For example:

`this.emit(':tell', 'Sometimes when I look at the Alexa skills you have all taught me, I just have to say, <say-as interpret-as="interjection">Bazinga.</say-as><break time="0.3s"/><amazon:effect name="whispered"> I love it. </amazon:effect>')`

`this.emit(':tell', '<say-as interpret-as="interjection">Oh boy</say-as><break time="1s"/> this is just an example.')`

It will be included in the README.md file, there's [this](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/pull/101/files) PR for that now